# Custom permalinks with NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, nextgen-gallery

I set wordpress default permalinks to `/%category%/%postname%/`. I'm using NextGen Gallery. So when i use imagebrowser instead of jQuery effect in NG Gallery, it creates custom url for every image like `category/postname/?pid=no.` where category,postname and no. varies. I just want to change it into `image/no.`, where `image` should be a fix word. And url rewrite should work only with nextgen image, it should not affect the wordpress post urls. So help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Bro its too easy just go to options page and make an tick to enable parmalinks and add some text you want in the given box 
 [image: screenshot]

there ends the matter you can check
[Pullaice gallery](http://gallery.pullaice.com/)

Comment: I left nextgen gallery because of so many bugs and no support, btw may be they provided this feature in new updates.